# Laravel - Can't put the id of authenticated user in array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to put the id of authenticated user in the associative array.

**Code**

```
const USER_RULES = [
    'email' => "required|unique:users,email," . Auth::user()->id . "|email",
];
```

Above code generates the following error:

```
Constant expression contains invalid operations
```

Comment: PHP version? Before PHP 5.6 arrays can't be declared constant. If it is 5.6+ replace " . Auth::user()->id . " with a value just to check if the error is there.

Comment: Mine php version is 7.0

Comment: Getting the authenticated user id should be Auth::id();

Comment: If I put a constant in place of Auth::user()->id it works fine. But in this scenario, i can't pass current user id. :(

Comment: With Auth::id() it shows the same error?

Comment: Yep same error appears.

Comment: Why are you event trying to make a constant for `USER_RULES`? Why not just use a simple `array` with `$` sign?

Comment: @prateekkathal In Laravel this is a good convention to put your request validation rules as a constant in Model.

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmed I don't believe it is a good practice... I myself have never seen such an example in the Laravel Documentation. I might have missed it. Where did you learn this? Can i have a link to the url that says this is a good practice? I would definitely like to know why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use  expressions like `Auth::user()->id` in the PHP constants. It's only possible to provide a scalar expression (numeric and string literals). Check documentation for details:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php

Answer (score 3):

From official [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php):

The value must be a constant expression, **not** (for example) a variable, a property, or a function call.